# Token support in spring cloud consul

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, consul

We are using spring-cloud to read the configuration for our application. We have the similar structure like below in application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: consul_host
      port: 8500
```

We want to enable ACL for consul. So we need to pass [consul token](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/acl.html) to read the configuration by spring.
How can I specify consul token in application.yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use at least Spring Cloud Brixton M2 (current version is RC1), there is the property `spring.cloud.consul.config.acl-token` where you can specify the token.

Comment: From where you got this detail? It will be useful for reference

Comment: From the source code (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulConfigProperties.java)

Comment: From here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulConfigProperties.java#L55, it seems spring.cloud.consul.config.token is being used. Am I missing anything?

Comment: As far as i understand it, these are properties which are probably kept for backward compatibility. The Spring Boot configuration property mechanism resolves to the property name in my answer (which is suggested by the IDE completion mechanism and should be used in new projects).

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is to have token placed in following way:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: consul_host
      port: 8500
      token: your_token
```

I'm using Spring Boot version: "2.0.4.RELEASE" + "spring-cloud-starter-consul-config"